# Find subtree using recursive query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Given graph:

```
                A
            ____|_____
        (1)/ (2)|  (3)\
          AA    AB    AC
       ____|____
   (1)/ (2)| (3)\
    AAA   AAB   AAC
```

Order stored in relationships.

```
create
  (a:Node {title:"A", ordered:false, active: true}),
  (aa:Node {title:"AA", ordered: true, active: true}),
  (ab:Node {title:"AB", ordered: false, active: true}),
  (ac:Node {title:"AC", ordered: false, active: false}),
  (aaa:Node {title:"AAA", ordered: false, active: true}),
  (aab:Node {title:"AAB", ordered: false, active: true}),
  (aac:Node {title:"AAC", ordered: false, active: true}),
  (a)-[:RELATED_WITH { order: 1 }]->(aa),
  (a)-[:RELATED_WITH { order: 2 }]->(ab),
  (a)-[:RELATED_WITH { order: 3 }]->(ac),
  (aa)-[:RELATED_WITH{ order: 1 }]->(aaa),
  (aa)-[:RELATED_WITH{ order: 2 }]->(aab),
  (aa)-[:RELATED_WITH{ order: 3 }]->(aac)
return *;
```

For a given start node (for example "A"), I need to find all subnodes, but I can only go down to active nodes (active = true). Also, if a node has the "ordered = true" property set, then I only need to descend to the first active node.

For example, for the graph above, a subtree is expected to be found:

```
       A
      / \
     AA AB
      |
     AAA
```

How to make a select (match) query to get this result?

Comment: when ordered=true, how do you get the first active node? Is the first node sorted by title?

Comment: @jose_bacoy Relations contains "order" property

Comment: @jose_bacoy Perhaps it would be easier to store information about order directly in the nodes.  I will be glad if I get information on how to solve this problem with this assumption.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
MATCH path = (a:Node{title: 'A'})-[*]-(b{active:true}) 
RETURN path
```

It will give you the subtree starting from node A, with every other leaf node or intermediate node, having active property as true.